# How to capture verbal contribution commitments: invoice, contribution pending or pledge?

Tags: contributions, pledges

If a constituent makes a verbal commitment (ie. at event or via phone campaign) to make a one-time donation (ie. pledge) and we want to track + invoice them to fulfill that pledge, what is the best way to process via online self-service?

It looks like Pledges are designed for this, however:

- They require an installment period.  We only have a commitment for a
  one-time donation.
- We need to ensure the payment matches / fulfills the pledge.  Is there a special link for a pledge fulfillment/payment online?  If not, the system will consider the pledge unpaid and continue to send reminders.

Alternatively, we can create a contribution with payment pending (or create a Pledged status type)

- How do you send an email invoice and ensure that the payment matches the pending contribution?
- Is there a way to construct the URL so the payment marks the contribution as complete?

I'd be open to using webforms - This seems like a common use-case.

Comment: I realize there is more coming in 4.7 (that may be the "answer") but hoping to discover a best-practice in 4.6.x.  I noticed that the contribution API has Action - "completetransaction" which seems to be related and I also see a "pledgepayment" API which leads me to believe that this capability exists - hopefully without writing an extension.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately pledges do not work with online contribution forms the way you'd like without an extension. You can use the framework for partial payments that's available in github and [seen at the CiviCon in Denver earlier this year](https://denver2015.civicrm.org/sessions/frontend-partial-payments-development-framework)

First you'll need to create the contribution(not a pledge) on the back end. You probably can use the same concept with a checksum email if you don't want to require a login.

Comment: This seems like it will work (readme specifies this is for event participants, but presume i can use a contribution without event).  Will see if the cost to maintain this is the right fit - but thanks for the tip!